# How to prove $|f'(x)| \leq 1$ when $f(x)$ has higher-order derivatives?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose that the function $f(x)$ has a second-order derivative,  $|f''(x)| \leqslant2,$ and $f(0)=f(1)=0$.  Prove: $|f'(x)|\leqslant$1

I have proved it when $f(x)$ has only second-order derivative:
$$0=f(0)=f(x)+f'(x)(-x)+ \frac{f''(x)}{2} x^2$$

$$1=f(1)=f(x)+f'(x)(1-x)+ \frac{f''(x)}{2} (1-x)^2$$

$$\Rightarrow f'(x)=\frac{f''(x)}{2}[x^2-(1-x)^2]=\frac{f''(x)}{2}(2x-1)$$

$$\Rightarrow |f'(x)|\leqslant\frac{f'(x)}{2}=1$$

But how to solve it when $f(x)$ has higher order derivative?

Comment: Your first equation starting $0=f(0)=\dots$ is not accurate - you don’t get equality, only approximation.

Comment: You can use the fact that the error in the taylor series $f(x+a)\approx f(x)+af^\prime (x)$ is equal to $\frac{a^2}{2}f^{\prime\prime}(c)$ *for some* $c\in(x,x+a)$. Then your original proof goes through.

Comment: It’s not clear what you mean by “if $f$ has higher order derivatives.” As long as the condition is still $|f’’(x)|\leq 2,$ you get the same proof. Do you want the condition to be on the higher derivative?